# write a program that prints a nested loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-loops

I'm trying to print a nested loops that looks like this:

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9 10 11 12
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def main11():
    for n in range(1,13)
        print(n, end=' ')
```

however, this prints the numbers in one line: 1 2 3 4 5 6  7 8 9 10 11 12

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Do I Make a List of Numbers Line Break at a Certain Point?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556242/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-numbers-line-break-at-a-certain-point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using string formatting:

```
for i in range(1,13):
    print '{:2}'.format(i),
    if i%4==0: print

[OUTPUT]
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12
```

Answer (score 1):

[Modulus Operator (%)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

```
for n in range(1,13):
  print(n, end=' ')
  if n%4 == 0:
    print
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for offset in range(3):
    for i in range(1,5):
        n = offset*4 + i
        print(n, end=' ')
    print()
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 
9 10 11 12
```

Or if you want it nicely formatted the way you have in your post:

```
for offset in range(3):
    for i in range(1,5):
        n = offset*4 + i
        print("% 2s"%n, end=' ')
    print()
```

Output:

```
 1  2  3  4 
 5  6  7  8 
 9 10 11 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when you write a for loop, you should check if this is the right implementation.
From the requirements you have, I would write something like this:

```
NB_NB_INLINE = 4
MAX_NB = 12
start = 1
while start < MAX_NB:
    print( ("{: 3d}" * NB_NB_INLINE).format(*tuple( j+start for j in range(NB_NB_INLINE))) )
    start += NB_NB_INLINE
```